# How can I generate another element in list if numbers of duplicates are higher than given number

Tags: python

I' ve got problem like this one for example i have list which I' m generating and number of possible duplicates m :

```
n = 4  # num of random elements in list (which are letters)
m = 2  # num of possible duplicates of letter if that's more than m the
```

given letter need to be swapped for another one which doesn't disrupts logic

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']  # and now "B" is generated so this need be automatically swapped
```

I have to generate another letter which is not for example "A" because than len of A will be  == 3

example output:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

That the way I tryed to solve it

```
# n is number of elements,
# m is number of possible duplicates
# both are generated before

import string
import random
from collections import Counter

 @classmethod
    def generate_string(cls, n, m):
        return [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) if j > m else i for i, j in
                Counter([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(0, n)]).items()]
```

Comment: What is your question about your code?

Comment: do  you want to keep n number of duplicate in continous array of character and remove extra duplicate?

Comment: Question is about given problem, in code i wrote my way to solve it which one doesnt works

Comment: so n is number of elements in list that can be 5 if I get duplicate when i m genering list this letter need to be swapped to another one

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The problem in this code is the generate number can make problem with len of duplicates for another one for example i have m = 2  list = ["a, "b, "b". "b" ,"a"] and now b can be swapped to a which one make error in program logic because thats return  ["a, "b, "b". "a" ,"a"] which is not valid

Comment: Ok, what you're trying to do is: find duplicate letters inside an array. If the count of a group of duplicated letters surpasses the value of `m`, than these duplicated letters must be changed to another letter, so the array gets only `m` repetitions of the same letter. Is that it?

Comment: what should it be swapped for? what if i remove 2 instances of the same letter? what should those be swapped for? not clear

Comment: And, you also must solve this using a generator expression (one line of code). It cannot be solved with multiple lines of code. Right?

Comment: To be precise i generate list n is number of elements for list if n = 5  the list have 5  elements so i generate random letters and I've got m = 3 <-- numbers of possible duplicates so when i generate next letter and i 've got more than 3 the same should generate another one

Comment: Just trying to understand it, because the explanation is very confusing.

Comment: that's can be solved in multiply lines expression

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way: what is your native language? Have you checked if there is a stack overflow in that language? For example, the Spanish-language stack overflow is es.stackoverflow.com. I think you might have better luck posting your question in your native language as it is very difficult to understand what you are asking here.

Comment: @ddejohn I rewrote the question, maybe now will be more easy to understand

Comment: If no character can have more than `m` repeats, can't you just take `[char for _ in range(m) for char in possible_letters]`? Or are you attempting to generate random sequences with this constraint? It's still not really clear what you're trying to do. Can you give some examples of inputs and your expected outputs for them?

Comment: @ddejohn I really don't know that can be write more clearly n = number of elements in list / m = number of possible duplicates. I'm generating letters in range(0, n) if in list i have before genearte letter for example two "A" when possible numbers of elements is 2 and i have anothe two elements in list which are two "B" that program need to genearte another letter than "B" or "A"  for example i ve got ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']  and program can not generate any of this lattters because limit is 2 for duplicates so possible output can be  ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want a randomly generated list of length `n` consisting of of letters where no letter is repeated more than `m` times. If so, you can duplicate your list of letters `m` times so that there is exactly `m` copies of each letter, and then take a random sample of size `n` from that population:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as alpha
import random


def generate_letters(n, m):
    return random.sample(alpha * m, n)
```

Demos:

```py
In [4]: generate_letters(10, 2)
Out[4]: ['O', 'I', 'C', 'R', 'V', 'Z', 'P', 'F', 'D', 'L']

In [5]: generate_letters(5, 3)
Out[5]: ['B', 'S', 'J', 'B', 'O']

In [6]: generate_letters(9, 5)
Out[6]: ['S', 'V', 'D', 'O', 'K', 'U', 'W', 'Z', 'C']
```

Comment: That's the very good answear however sometimes I've "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative"

Comment: Well of course. If it's not possible to generate a list of length `n` with a maximum of `m` repeats allowed, then what do you expect should returned? If I give you two letters, `"A"` and `"B"`, and ask you to make me a list of length `n=6`, with no letter repeating more than `m=2` times... what should the output be?

Comment: Oh yeah u be right, thanks that is very good answear

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random
import string

n = #
m = #

rand_list = []
for _ in range(n):
    rand_char = (random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
    while rand_list.count(rand_char) >= m:
        rand_char = (random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
    rand_list.append(rand_char)

print(rand_list)
```

Comment: That's the half - right answear however that works after moment when list is generated that the biggest problem

Comment: Okay so you want the output randomized?

Comment: I updated the solution. I think this new approach is better. Have a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: That works in right way, thank you in advance